# Most efficient way to verify multiple html table row inputs in a JS cycle?

Tags: javascript, html

Very much appreciated if you can help me since I am a newbie on this.
I have a huge html table with more than 10 columns and around 20 rows.

I want to do a javascript cycle to verify the inputs of all the rows. My strategy was to insert Ids in each  in which each row's id always increases +1. For example:

```
<td><input id="ingredient_percentage_1" type="text" name=" " form="form1" />%</td>
<td><input id="ingredient_percentage_2" type="text" name=" " form="form2" />%</td>
```

The code I've done is like this:

```
function verifyPercentages(){

  var total = 0;
  var i;

  if (batch.value === "") {
    alert ("Please insert value in Batch Size field");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (i=1; i<19; i++){
      var percentage = document.getElementById('ingredient_percentage_'+i);
      if( (((i>1) && (i<5)) || (i==11) || (i==13)) && (percentage.value == "")) {
        alert ("Mandatory fields are not filled up");
        return false;
      }
      if ((i>6) && (i<9) && (percentage.value == "")) {
        alert ("Please select an option in the Product type field above");
        return false;
      }
      if ((i>8) && (i<11) && (percentage.value >= 1)) {
        alert ("Please make sure that the percentages for oil are less than 1%");
        return false;
      }
      if ((i>14) && (i<17) && (percentage.value >= 1)) {
        alert ("Please make sure that (...)");
        return false;
      }
      if (percentage == null) continue;
    }

    calculatePercentages();
  }
}
```

But I feel that is not very optimized. Is there a more efficient/clean way to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: I think a look into time complexity as a subject would interest you. What do you consider efficient, smaller, less code? Or faster, based on the time complexity of a function.

Comment: A more generic approach is to loop over the collection of row elements and query for inputs by their class within each specific row instance. Approach doesn't need to know how many rows there are ( loop checks length of the collection) and doesn't require incrementing ids

Comment: @Catherine, are you attempting a pure Javascript solution or an HTML solution also since it is tagged in HTML.

Comment: @Raymond In this case I would say smaller (aka 'clean') code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to use Javascript's `querySelectorAll` with enumeration. Also, many other approaches. In the example below I provide alternative ways to iterate over the HTML elements. I comment where the respected logic should go

The bottom example uses the `querySelectorAll` to match partially matching id string name values.

The below selector example means to locate an element where the attribute id that does begin with the string **"ingredient_"**.

**Implementations Documentation**

- [Document Query Selector All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Document Query Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

### Note

- `^` matches the start
- `*` matches any position
- `$` matches the end

**Edits:** Comparison `element.value == ""` may cause unexpected type coercion. That is why you may notice the if statement logic changed a little from your initial code provided.

```js
  
function verify() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll(`[id ^= "ingredient_`);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, callback);

  function callback(element, i) {
    if ((((i > 1) && (i < 5)) || (i === 11) || (i === 13)) && (element.value === "")) {
      // Logic
    }
    if ((i > 6) && (i < 9) && (element.value === "")) {
      // Logic
    }
    if ((i > 8) && (i < 11) && (element.value >= 1)) {
      // Logic
    }
    if ((i > 14) && (i < 17) && (element.value >= 1)) {
      // Logic
    }

    // Debug
    console.log('i:', i, 'id:', element.id, 'value:', element.value)

  }


}

verify();
```

```html
<td><input id="ingredient_percentage_1" type="text" name=" " value="1" form="form1" />%</td>
<td><input id="ingredient_percentage_2" type="text" name=" " value="2" form="form2" />%</td>
```

Comment: Thanks @Raymond! I hadn't thought of using querySelectorAll with enumeration, seems good!

Answer (score 2):

Not wanting to interfere with your tech choices, but you could do this very easily (and robust!) with built in html5 validation. It will work on all modern browsers. You can do more this way than you probably believe. One example of how an email input field in a form could be validated:

```
<input 
  id="useremail" 
  type="text" 
  placeholder="your.email@example.com" 
  required 
  minlength="6" 
  maxlength="90" 
  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" 
  title="Wrong email address format">
```

Result when error is thrown on Chrome/Brave/Chromium:

[image: input error html5]

A more precise error text above, albeit onerous, would be "The email must contain between 5 and 89 alphanumeric characters plus the '@'".

In order to run your function when the form fully validates you can add it into your submit event like so:

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector('.btn-submit')

submitButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   calculatePercentages()
})
```

Comment: Cool answer, I guess what do you do when you need to call his function's afterward. It all depends on if he needs Javascript for further calculations. But nice example. Would be better if you provide an example that pertains to his, e.g the regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Raymond, I updated the answer with a proposal for how he can get his function fired the same way once the form is ready to be submitted. I should add details that correspond better to his specific scenario, but as I don't know the exact validation constraints and because my solution is a bit on the side of what he asks for, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I thumb up, would have never thought to extend to strictly the HTML approach. Nice work. Maybe let him know, specific elements will require specific regex, it seems he is using Javascript based on each `id` number, for different validation expressions.

Comment: I see now that I have to start reading the spec better. I missed the extra conditional logic he has included on top of the pure input validation. This may be impossible to achieve the way I imagined it, but I'll leave my answer up to maybe give him an idea of how he maybe could separate input and JS logic.

Comment: it is possible. That is why I thumb's up to your post. He is just going to have to specify what logic manually for each input form. But a little work, and no more Javascript. It seems he only is validating certain input's and also, your answer might be best because some might be option choices. It just is simpler.

Comment: Great Raymond! I'll have to experiment more with the patterns I can make work in html myself. Also, to Catherine, sorry for calling you "he/him". Could not edit my comments to fix that. But these days, who knows what the pronouns should be :)

Comment: Thank you @anatolhiman. This is specific for validation right? I also use each <td> ids to modify their values in that other function called CalculatePercentges(). Is there a more global solution?

Comment: Yes, the html5 validation is for validation only, so the idea was to separate the concerns and run things in a chain that don't mix business logic with validation. First validate the input, once you have that you can run logic on it, then if you need you can manipulate the DOM to display something to the user by injecting new data on the html page, etc. Easier to wrap your head around it when you take it one step at the time.